# Couchbase Config File /etc/couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, configuration-files

So I am automating an installation of Couchbase.  My automation has a way in which it can take a path to a configuration file.  In Linux I usually configure /etc/fooapp/fooapp.conf
Is there a configuration file like this with couchbase?  Not sure if they followed a Posix compliant way to install and configure.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Couchbase installs itself into `/opt/couchbase`. It is distributed system and stores its configuration in its database. The best way to configure Couchbase -- is to use [configuration tools](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/cli/cbcli-intro.html), which come in distribution, its [REST API](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/rest-api/rest-intro.html) or [Admin UI](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/install/init-setup.html).

There are some [ansible scripts](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/ansible-couchbase-server/) published on labs account. For example, to  initialize cluster with multiple nodes:
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/ansible-couchbase-server/blob/master/examples/cluster_init.yml

I think these scripts can be easily ported to whatever system you are using to automate your deployment.

There is also guide about deployment Couchbase into containers:
https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/install/running-couchbase-in-containers.html

Comment: Thanks bro I appreciate that.  Looks like I will need to use the REST API or the ansible playbooks.  Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you very well do have a config file. It will be situated at :

```
/opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase/static_config
```

The default settings may not be there, but you can always add it to the file. Suppose if you want to change few default ports, then add the following (I just assumed the new port numbers as 9000,8999,12000 ):

```
{rest_port, 9000}.                                   
{mccouch_port, 8999}.                         
{memcached_port, 12000}.
```